# Why does spawn/exec takes larger time with large number of sub-processes created?

Tags: node.js, process, operating-system

Created a simple program in node.js which very simply spawn/exec a hello world program in python, and can fork n number of processes in parallel.

These are the stats below for the same:

[image]

COUNT: Number of sub-processes forked in parallel

AVG/MIN/MAX: average/min/max time taken for the forked process to complete

NOTE: python program which was forked does not do anything, just print "Hello World" to console

Can see the complete code [here](https://gist.github.com/gitcloned/1168200bd3b3a7cafb0cad8dfc2ee151)

Comment: Can you add your code how do you spawn/fork the child processes?

Comment: Have attached the code above, thanks